# Can change forecolor but not backcolor of textbox in async task

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to change colors of a textbox as stated above, I'm just gonna show the code because I think that would be the most fitting explanation.

```
    private async Task Disco()
    {
        int duration;
        switch (ptr)
        {
            default:
                //duration = 900;//15 min
                duration = 10;
                break;
            case 1:
                duration = 50;
                //duration = 1800;//30 min
                break;
        }

        int color = 0;
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (duration-- != 0)
            {
                TB.ForeColor = foreground[color];
                TB.BackColor = background[color];
                if (++color == foreground.Length)
                    color = 0;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });

        TB.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
```

The forecolor has been working fine, but when I added the backcolor line it throws

> "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code
> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TB' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

How is this even possible???

I'm literally accessing it in the line above with the forecolor, why is the backcolor behaving different???

If I make the backcolor line a comment everything is fine again....

Making a static var for the textbox does not help.

I am using .net 3.1(for win 7) but that should not be the problem here.

Comment: You should use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @hijinxbassist how does that help the backcolor? the delay is not the issue here.

Comment: How are `foreground` and `background` defined? I infer they are arrays, and probably belong to the form or control this code is embedded in.

Comment: Are you sure that the error isn't coming from your next-to-last line, `TB.ForeColor = Color.Black`?

Comment: @AnnL. they are both arrays with 6 colors in them. i'm very sure it's the background line, like i have already stated, when i comment out the background line the problem is fixed

Comment: You should Invoke all of the ui calls, since they are not running on the ui thread.

Comment: It's just a lucky coincidence that the setter for ForeColor executes without exception on a thread other than the UI thread. Modification of UI elements is supposed to be done only in the context of the UI thread, though.

Comment: @hijinxbassist i tried invoke and that fixed it, not before have to remove the newly added task.delay which for some reason didn't add delay?

Comment: You need to await the task delay, that is likely why it didnt delay.  The issue with using Sleep in this context is that it will block all execution on that thread, which prevents async from reusing that thread to do other work.  It might not be an issue now, but it can cause problems later down the road in more complex code.

Comment: @hijinxbassist ah, can't believe I forgot await, will add. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As hijinxbassist and MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace stated, I got lot lucky with the foreground and had to invoke the UI calls.